# multiple segues in uitableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a uitableview with 2 custom cells (messages, and notifications). I want to apply a segue to another viewcontroller when user press the message cell, but do nothing when he press the notification cell. how to do this with didselectrowatindexpath method? some answers here suggested using indexpath.row for checking which cell is clicked but I get these dynamic cells from json so I don't know where their position is in the tableview or how many are they.

using swift and xcode 7.3

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried so far, and point out what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are different types, you can just determine the class type in didselectrowatindexpath

Or you can add a different tag to the cells. You can do this in the storyboard or programatically when you create the cell.

Then in didselectrowatindexpath check what the tag is for the selected row and you will know what type of cell it is.

Comment: yes they are of different types(different classes), how to check for the type?

Comment: if let cell = cell as? MessageType {
    // of MessageType
}
else {
    // NotificationType    
}    Where MessageType is the name of your message cell class

Comment: Just drag out the segue in the storyboard from the MessageTpye prototype cell.